# jQuery text with new lines

Tags: jquery

```
var text = $('div').text();
alert(text);
```

When converting html to text with jQuery it removes the html elements include the break tags. My goals is to convert break tags to new lines and then convert to text but every attempt doesn't work. The fiddle has a non working example of what I'm trying to accomplish. The fiddle is at

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3f2s7zp/4/)

Comment: Code **always** goes in your question first. Don't try to game the system.

Comment: That's a hacky fix. I edited it to play by the rules...

Comment: this is not the fix... you should include code just like what the warning says that you ignored

Comment: j08691. Thanks for making an assumption and then not helping. You must live an exciting life!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `<br>` tags with newlines:

```
var text = $('div').html().replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, '\n');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v3f2s7zp/5/

Note that this will match any classnames or other attributes, like `<br class="large">`. Which is ofcourse of good thing!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not achieving your goal, is because $('div').text() will output the parsed html. To get the expected result, first you need to extract the raw html. The following snippet will display an alert box. Note that the br tags were replaced by new line characters:

```js
    var text = $('div').html().replace(/<br(\s)?(\/)?>/g, '\n');
    alert(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=text>Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.<br /><br />
Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Proin eget tortor risus. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a.<br /><br />'</div>
```